# Sometimes socket dies when switching wifi to 3g iOS posix sockets

Tags: ios, sockets, posix

I've searched the web extensively but haven't found a good answer to this.

Im writing a socket based application in C++ using posix sockets on iOS/Android.

When switching from wifi->3g, *SOMETIMES* the socket goes dead without giving any errors when reading/writing.

I can use the reachability API on iOS (and similar on android) to detect when the network switches.

I am destroying/recreating the socket when this occurs. The problem is if the socket is alive, the server will receive the signal when I close the socket. If the server receives the close signal, it will assume the client disconnected intentionally and notify others about this, which is not what I want. If the socket is dead, the server doesn't receive this signal and everything is OK.

How do other people handle this scenario? I really don't want to use a timeout to detect this.

Why does it only *sometimes* die too? And how can I tell the socket is actually dead?

Comment: If you aren't getting any error on `read` and `write` how do you declare the  socket to be dead?

Comment: Thats the problem. There is a heartbeat between the client and server, so when I watch the logs and see that stop, I know its dead. The problem is detecting this without waiting for some timeout, and then being able to recreate the socket if the network switched

Comment: May I ask if you found a solution to this problem? We kind of have the same problem.

Comment: Hey there, 

There really is no solution from what I found. It's just the nature of how sockets work. It's up to you how to handle it. 

What I did was add a heartbeat to check if the socket was still alive. Basically a timeout. When either the heartbeat expired, or any kind of socket error occurred, I would trash the socket and create a fresh one and send some kind of 'reconnect' packet to the server. On receiving this packet the server would resend any unacknowledged packets to the client and vice-versa leaving both the client and server in sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this issue, this is the approach I'm taking.

When switching networks, I'm sending a ping-and-reconnect packet to the server, AND creating a new socket.

Which ever responds first, I close the other connection.

Required a bit of server side changes to handle this correctly too